# How to add a network drive to windows 11 (if the option is not there)?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11

On a windows 11 system I want to add a network drive to the File Explorer. This is explained in various pages (see e.g. [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d#ID0EBD=Windows_11) and [HERE](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-map-network-drive-windows-11/)), but it becomes annoying when you only see the following:

[image]

I followed the instructions I found [HERE](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-map-network-drive-missing/) and [HERE](https://www.digitbin.com/fix-windows-11-map-network-drive-missing/) (i.e. enabling network discovery, editing the registry, rebooting the PC) but the entry

```
Map network drive
```

is still missing. Can I still add a network drive (i.e. something that start with `\\some_domain.com\path\to\something`) to windows, or do I have to buy a new PC/install some other OS?

**Addition:**

I installed some tools on that windows PC and now the option to add a network drive appeared magically. I did not reboot the PC. What is going on??? Does this option appear only randomly?

Comment: Does running `pushd \\some_domain.com\path\to\something` from a command prompt work?

Comment: @berend It is about the missing/not missing option. You seem to have misunderstood my question...

Comment: Yes,  maybe your question isn't very clear ;-)

Comment: @Berend I was just wondering why this option I was missing just suddenly pops up later? How/what can go on? Does windows has a sleep somewhere and then decide to show this option some time later...??

Comment: Yes, but the title is now *How to add a network drive to windows 11 if the option is not there*. If that is not your question, please update it

Answer (score 0):

In Explorer, select This PC. With This PC selected, you can choose Map Network Drive from the menubar or from the context menu. The secret in Windows 11 is to make sure that This PC is currently selected.

Comment: Yeah.. Windows 11 doesn't show the "map network drive" button anymore in File Explorer. It still is in the right-mouse-button-click menu that you get when you click on "This PC" or "Network" the left-hand panel. Microsoft seems to be wanting to push everyone away from using drive-maps and now heavily favors "pinning" items to the left-hand panel.

Comment: @Tonny ... which has absolutely no effect on the command line or in PowerShell. Makes sense, right? *rolls eyes* That's MS logic.

Comment: Microsoft and logic.... Those don't always mix very well. I can sort of grok the MS desire to dumb down the user-interface though for users that are barely computer literate. Which probably is 95% of their user-base these days. Most people only have a vague idea what a file is, how big it is and were it is really located on their computer. But at least keep the full feature-set available for power-users (if only with a item in the menu to switch them on/off). Anyways File Explorer is not my thing. Proper 2-panel file-manager for me. (TotalCommander is so much better.)